# Rake db:setup does not run rails db:migrate, schema.rb does not exist error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rake, rails-migrations, schema.rb

On Rails 6, i expect `rake db:setup` to perform `db:create`, `db:migrate` and `db:seed`
i have only one data model and the record creation for its table was written in `db/seeds.rb`

```
# db/seeds.rb
require 'csv'

csv_text = File.read(Rails.root.join('lib', 'seeds', 'seed_first_table.csv'))
csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => true, :encoding => 'ISO-8859-1')
csv.each_with_index do |row, index|
  cr = CatProfile.new
  puts "row #{index} saved"
end

puts "There are now #{CatProfile.count} rows in the table"
```

`database.yml` also has a new user credential which was created through `sudo -u postgres createuser -s new_user`

But `rake db:setup` returns:

```
Created database 'my_application_development'
Created database 'my_application_test'
my_application/db/schema.rb doesn't exist yet. Run `rails db:migrate` to create it, then try again. If you do not intend to use a database, you should instead alter /my_application/config/application.rb to limit the frameworks that will be loaded.
```

in `sudo -u postgres psql` it did make the databases but there are no relations (no seed table)

when I run `rails db:migrate`

```
== 20201103153526 CreateCatProfiles: migrating =================================
-- create_table(:cat_profiles)
   -> 0.0091s
== 20201103153526 CreateCatProfiles: migrated (0.0092s) ========================
```

then when I run `rake db:setup` a second time:

```
Database 'my_application_development' already exists
Database 'my_application_test' already exists
row 0 saved
row 1 saved 
...
row 1719 saved
There are now 1720 rows in the table
```

noticed that database already exists from the first `rake db:setup` but now it is able to seed the table

I dont understand why running `rake db:setup` the first time does not pick up necessary migrations before seeding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check out the [source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake#L352-L353) for `rails db:setup` you will see that `db:setup` does NOT run `db:migrate`

> Creates the database, loads the schema, and initializes with the seed data (use db:reset to also drop the database first)

`db:schema:load` loads what currently exists in your `schema.rb` into the database.